# How to create an isolated Linked Lists header with undefined type

Tags: c, types, linked-list

I would like to create a Linked Lists header that I could use in various projects. One essential feature that would be needed is that I could control the Linked List type inside my `main.c`. `main.c` would possibly look something like this:

```
#include "linkedlists.h"
#define NODE_TYPE int

int main() {
    /* code using linked lists of integers */
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, I'm defining the type inside `linkedlists.h` and then including it in `main.c`, but that means I need to change the Linked Lists header for every project. For instance, in my current project I have something like this, inside `linkedlists.h`:

```
struct A {                           
    char * name;                            
    int age;                   
};

struct B {                              
    char * name;                            
    char * description;                     
    char * schedule;                        
};

union node_type {                           
    struct A a;               
    struct B b;
};

typedef struct node {               
    union node_type data;       
    struct node * next;
} node;

/* linked lists function declarations */
```

So, if possible, how would I be able to move the list type specification to `main.c` and make `linkedlists.h` universal for any type of lists?

Comment: You can do it with `void *` data.  You need to consider whether the list is going to store a copy of the data it is given, or if it is only going to store the pointer itself.  Storing just the pointer is easy, but means that the code manipulating the lists must allocate separate space for each separate item.  Storing a copy of the data means you need to know how big the data item is, and the data must be copyable. (Not all structures are copyable — for example, entries in linked lists can't just be copied because the next and/or previous pointers are wrong when copied.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must "abstract" the list from its "payload", for example:

```
typedef struct node {               
    void *data;          // the user's data
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Your linked list functions now just put the data there and return it to the user, without knowing what that data is.

```
// list.h
struct list;
int addNode(struct list *list, void *data);  // add node with data to abstract list
void *getData(struct list *list);            // return data from abstract list
```

and:

```
// list.c
struct node {               
    void *data;          // the user's data
    struct node *next;
};

struct list {
    struct node *head, *current;
};

int addNode(struct list *list, void *data)
{
    struct node *newNode= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //...
    // (add node to list)
    newNode->data= data;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: you would probably also need an identifier field which will provide info about type mapping at use time.

Comment: @Serge, no you don't; anyway, not in the list module. But the user module could implement a union as the payload, and then the user module/type would need such an identifier to say what the union curently has.

Comment: makes sense, but then would the data have to be a pointer, or could it be anything?

Comment: Put: `struct list;` (and only that — no definition of the details of the structure type, so it is an opaque type) on a line on its own in the header, then use `int addNode(struct list *list, void *data);` and `void *getData(struct list *list);` in the declarations.  Using `void *` for everything leads to undiagnosable errors.  Also, there is no need for `typedef` for `struct node` since you never use plain `node`.  The `struct list` definition is bogus (no semicolon) and there's no name either, so the `typedef` isn't needed since you go on to use `struct list`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i wonder how you would you know which data type is correct for this particular list node? Unless the whole list is used with a particular type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank you for your excellent review comments! The plain `struct list` declaration is a beauty. Using `typedef` without name is an old habit to tell myself "hey, this is a type".

Comment: @Serge,trhe point is there is no "particular list". It is an abstract list that can store a pointer to anything the user wants to put there.

Comment: The one problem with this is that you can stuff a collection of heterogeneous pointers (pointers to different types) into a single list, and there's no way to tell when collecting the values which of the various types a given pointer corresponds to.  There isn't an easy way around this.  You can devise a macro-based strategy to define the list functions for a given pointer type, building the type into the function name (`##` operator).  It isn't always clear that it is worth the effort; I tend not to do that (any more) and live with the risk.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the user must keep track of what he puts there. The user can create multiple lists (`createList` function required), one for each type of object, or could put a union with a differentiator (`struct X{int what; union Y{...};}`)